# change background color of custom UIButton (CoreGraphics) when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, core-graphics, drawrect

Does someone know how to change the background color of a custom UIButton?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nAIR.png)

As you can see in the image the button named plot has a background color of orange. But the button left to it(the black triangle) is not in orange.

What I want is when I press button "plot" or "award" the triangle button next to it also change with it.

Here is my code:

```
@IBDesignable class LeadingButton: UIButton {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    // *Draw triangle button:

    // Create context for triangle
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // *Put information into context:

    // Info for drawing triangle:
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 17, 0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 40)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 17, 40)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 17, 0)

    // Info color triangle
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)

    // Color in triangle with specified color
    CGContextFillPath(context)

    // Draw triangle
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
}

class MovieDetailController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   // For changing background color of buttons
        self.buttonArray = [plotB, directorB, writerB, actorsB, countryB, awardB, posterB, leadingB, trailingB]

    }

    func isButton(pressed: Int) {

        switch pressed {
        case 0...8:

            let selectedButton = buttonArray[pressed]
            selectedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

            var idDictionary = [0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6]
            idDictionary.removeValueForKey(pressed)

            for (_, value) in idDictionary {

                if value == 6 {

                }
                else {

                    let remainButtons = buttonArray[value]
                    remainButtons.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                }
            }

        default:
            print("test")
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your drawing code into a drawing function like so:

```
func drawTriangle() {
    //Move draw rect code into here
}
```

and call this function from drawRect. Also make sure to call the super in drawRect

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    drawTriangle()
}
```

Then you can add a variable onto the button to dictate it's colour and in the did set you can set the triangles colour

```
var triangleColor:UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() {
    didSet {
        drawTriangle()
    }
}
```

Then just take the colour when you draw the triangle:

Replace:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
```

With:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, triangleColor.CGColor)
```

Then you should be able to just check if the button you press is Plot/Award and set the corresponding buttons colour using:

```
(triangleButtonVariable).triangleColor = YourColour
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work. I also get a warning in my debug console: <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable. Is it because you can't call drawRect whenever you want? I read it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If the setting of the new colour is not being done inside (or from) drawRect, you will get the Invalid Context error.

Try setting the new colour, and then telling the button to setNeedsDisplay()